# How to put a value into an input field using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Using ajax, the number is echoed in php `echo $response;` Then in the Jquery, I'd like to put this number into a field called 'total one'. How can I do this?

Code so far:

**In php file**

```
echo $response;
```

**In Jquery file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#formsubmit').click(function() {
                $.post(
                PT_Ajax.ajaxurl, {
                    action: 'ajax-inputtitleSubmit',
                    numberofwelds: $('input[name=numberofwelds]').val(),
                    numberofconwelds: $('input[name=numberofconwelds]').val(),
                    nextNonce: PT_Ajax.nextNonce
                }, function(response) {
                    $('#totalone').val(response);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

**UPDATE**

The `console.log` just displays the number I'm trying to display in the `#totalone` field. There aren't any errors in the JS console.

**PHP that creates the Ajax response to send back to Jquery :**

```
 function myajax_inputtitleSubmit_func() {
        $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];   
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    $numwelds = isset($_POST['numberofwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofwelds'] : '';
$numconwelds = isset($_POST['numberofconwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofconwelds'] : '';

if (is_numeric($numwelds) && is_numeric($numconwelds))
{
    $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
} 
}
```

**Form HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formsubmit" id="formsubmit"   >
<h1> Process </h1>
<p> operation type always robot </p>
Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" id="numberofwelds"  >
<br /> <br />
Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" id="numberofconwelds"  >
<br /> <br />
Total one: <input type="text" name="totalone" id="totalone" disabled>
<br /> <br />
<input type="submit"  value="Calculate" id="submit" name="submit" class="ajax-link" >
<div id="result"> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That is how you set the value of a field: http://jsfiddle.net/QW8U6/. Any javascript errors in the console? Have you logged the value of `response`? Are you sure `$('#totalone')` selects the element?

Comment: There aren't any errors in the console. When I replace `$('#totalone').val(response); with `console.log( response );` the number is displayed in the console. `#totalone` is the id, i've put that above too.

Comment: Can you also post your form/HTML?

Comment: @LShetty It's working!! Thanks so much. I changed the single quotations to double. Slightly confused why that works

Comment: Right, which one? my answer? if yes, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the  single quotation marks here `$('#totalone').val(response);` to double like this    `$("#totalone").val(response);` . It seems to be working now, & I don't quite understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this one. change val() to text()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#formsubmit').click(function() {
                $.post(
                PT_Ajax.ajaxurl, {
                    action: 'ajax-inputtitleSubmit',
                    numberofwelds: $('input[name=numberofwelds]').val(),
                    numberofconwelds: $('input[name=numberofconwelds]').val(),
                    nextNonce: PT_Ajax.nextNonce
                }, function(response) {
                    $('#totalone').text(response);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some extra brackets and so on in your code. Here is the cleaned up version which may just work:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('#formsubmit').click(function(){
        $.post(
            PT_Ajax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'ajax-inputtitleSubmit',
                numberofwelds : $('input[name=numberofwelds]').val(),
                numberofconwelds : $('input[name=numberofconwelds]').val(),
                nextNonce : PT_Ajax.nextNonce
            },
            function( response ) {
                $("#totalone").val(response);
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: post the log output pls.

Comment: the `console.log` just displays the number that I'm trying to display in the `#totalone` field, there aren't any errors in the JS console.

Comment: @lshetty i tried your code, but that doesn't seem to work either. The Jquery is for wordpress, so I think the extra brackets are necessary. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mattnewbie, jQuery is jQuery, doen't matter where you use it. And do you really need 2 "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {"

Comment: And what do you see in the console log?

Comment: @LShetty OK. I'll removed them. I still can't get the number to display in the `#totalone` field, thank-you anyway.

Comment: @mattnewbie, post yout form/HTML please.

Comment: @LShetty The `console.log` displays the number I'm trying to get into the field, when I use `console.log`. There aren't any errors in JS console.